# Using shared UDP Socket in Jersey REST Api

Tags: rest, asynchronous, concurrency, jersey-2.0

I am developing a simple rest service with jersey and jetty, which gets some requests from the clients and sends the prepared request further to another software (which is not made by me). The software sends some messages back that must be analyzed and sends back to the client. Therefore I've developed a new thread called SocketReceiver which starts after the request ist send to the software. This class uses a helper class which stores the connection to the udp socket (implemented as singleton). The solution works perfect as long as I have only one request per time. If two requests (from two separate clients) are made, there is a concurrency issue and no response is written back to the client by jersey.

Here's the run method of the socket receiver:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    byte[] message = new byte[9999];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);

    while (returnedObject == null) {
        logger.debug("Waiting for incomming message ...");
        try {
            onDemandInfoServer.getDataRadioSocket().receive(p);

            MessageFrame messageFrame = new MessageFrame(message);

            // CHECK Length (2. and 3. byte) and CODE (first byte)
            if ((message[1] == 0 && message[2] == 0) || !(message[0] == DC_Constants.D_Code
                    || message[0] == DC_Constants.G_Code || message[0] == DC_Constants.P_Code)) {
                logger.warn("wrong message!");
                continue;
            }

            int length = messageFrame.getLength();
            if (length > message.length) {
                logger.warn("wrong message!");
                continue;
            }

            byte[] msg = new byte[length];
            System.arraycopy(message, 0, msg, 0, length);

            logger.debug(LogHelper.getDataAsString(msg));

            if (message[0] == DC_Constants.P_Code) {
                msg = messageIsParanet(messageFrame);
            }

            MessageFrame msgFrame = new MessageFrame(msg);
            if (!msgFrame.isAcknowledge()) {
                newMessageFromDataradio(msgFrame);
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // error handling
        }
    }
    asyncResponse.resume(returnedObject); // returned objects sets when messages being analyszed
}
```

And here's a example jersey rest service:

```
@Path("/trips")
public class RequestTripListService extends BaseRestService {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestTripListService.class);

@POST
@Compress
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void logonToBlock(TripListRequest tripListRequest, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                         @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    // Send message via udp
    byte[] logonTelegramm = createLogonTelegramm(sequenceNumber);
    getOnDemandInfoServer().sendToDataRadio(logonTelegramm);

    // Build a new socket receiver and execute it
    JourneyOnDemandInfo info = new JourneyOnDemandInfo(terminal, tripListRequest.getBlockNo(), 0, 0, sequenceNumber);
    SocketReceiver<TripListUpdate> socketReceiver = new SocketReceiver<>(asyncResponse,
            getOnDemandInfoServer(), getXmlCodec(), info, TripListUpdate.class);
    socketReceiver.start();
}
}
```

1. What is the correct and thread safe way to use a shared udp socket?
2. How can I solve my problem described above?

Thanks for your help!